# Change color of selected li option with D3/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am creating a list of unique values (from a JSON query) using D3.js and I want to change the color of the text for the selected li. The function that does that is given underneath the snippet. My problem is that the color does not reset when I click on another value from the list.

```js
//JSON Data
const data = [
{
    "date": "2008-11",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-11",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 7.8
  }
];

//Parses date for correct time format
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

//Format data for the filter list (or dropdown) function
function formatData(data) {

  var valueMap = {}; 
  var mainFields = ["date", "num"]; 
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.num = +d.num;

    var Value = d.Value; 
    valueMap[Value] = []; 
    mainFields.forEach(function(field) { 
      valueMap[Value].push(d[field]); 
    }); 
  });

  return valueMap;
}

//Dropdown creation function
function dropDown() {

  // Handler for dropdown value change
  const valueMap = formatData(data);
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {
  
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    const newData = data.filter(function(item){
      return item.Value == d;
   });
    
    //Changes text color for the selected li option
    d3.select(this).style("color", "#c7003b");
 
  };

  // Get names of Values, for dropdown 
  var campaigns = Object.keys(valueMap).sort(); 

  var dropdown = d3.select("#dropdown") 
    .insert("ul", "svg") 
    .classed('selector', true) 


  dropdown.selectAll("li") 
    .data(campaigns) 
    .enter().append("li") 
     .attr("id", (function(d) { 
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length); 
    }))
    .text(function(d) { 
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length); 
    }) 
    .on("click", dropdownChange);
    


  var initialData = valueMap[campaigns[0]]; 

  
}


dropDown();
```

```css
/*css to go here*/

  body {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .flex-item1 {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .flex-item2 {
    width: 67%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .g-hed {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .g-source {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .g-intro {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }

  .g-labels {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    fill: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .g-chart {
      height: 100%;
  }
  .g-chart svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px 3px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .axis text {
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .y.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .domain {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    stroke: #2f5491;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    fill: none;
  }

  .overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .focus {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .focus circle {
    fill: #5e8dc9;
  }

  ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .selector li {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:3px solid #e0e0e0;
 background: #fff;
 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="dropdown"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">

    <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
    <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

The function that has to change. I need to reset the CSS I guess on every click and change the color again for the selected li:

```
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {

    d3.select("svg").remove();
    const newData = data.filter(function(item){
            return item.Value == d;
    });

    //Changes text color for the selected li option
    d3.select(this).style("color", "#c7003b");

  };
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for your issue?

Comment: @Ms.Tamil http://jsfiddle.net/radomer/dzugksbn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than applying css inline using a `style` attribute, it's better to apply a css class to the element; you can then easily change how you display your 'active' elements without having dig into your JS code.

Let's assume that you're going to add a class `active` to whichever element is currently selected.

When you activate `dropdownChange`, you want to remove any existing `active` classes and add `active` the element that triggered `dropdownChange`. Happily, `this` is set to the element that triggered the event, so you can easily work from there:

```
// get the parent ul element, remove the `active` class from all children
this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach( (e) => {
  e.classList.remove('active');
} );
// add `active` to the element that triggered the function
this.classList.add('active');
```

In situ:

```js
//JSON Data
const data = [{
    "date": "2008-11",
    "Value": "A",
    "num": 7.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-11",
    "Value": "B",
    "num": 7.8
  }
];

//Parses date for correct time format
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

//Format data for the filter list (or dropdown) function
function formatData(data) {

  var valueMap = {};
  var mainFields = ["date", "num"];
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.num = +d.num;

    var Value = d.Value;
    valueMap[Value] = [];
    mainFields.forEach(function(field) {
      valueMap[Value].push(d[field]);
    });
  });

  return valueMap;
}

//Dropdown creation function
function dropDown() {

  // Handler for dropdown value change
  const valueMap = formatData(data);
  var dropdownChange = function(d) {

    d3.select("svg").remove();
    const newData = data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Value == d;
    });

    // get the parent ul element, remove `active` class from children
    this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach( (e) => {
      e.classList.remove('active');
    } );
    // mark this node as active
    this.classList.add('active');

  };

  // Get names of Values, for dropdown 
  var campaigns = Object.keys(valueMap).sort();

  var dropdown = d3.select("#dropdown")
    .insert("ul", "svg")
    .classed('selector', true)


  dropdown.selectAll("li")
    .data(campaigns)
    .enter().append("li")
    .attr("id", (function(d) {
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length);
    }))
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.replace(/_/g, ' ').slice(1, d.length);
    })
    .on("click", dropdownChange);



  var initialData = valueMap[campaigns[0]];


}


dropDown();
```

```css
/*css to go here*/

body {
  font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item1 {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item2 {
  width: 67%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.g-hed {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.g-source-bold {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.g-source {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.g-source-bold {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.g-intro {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.g-labels {
  font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.g-chart {
  height: 100%;
}

.g-chart svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-dasharray: 2px 3px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: #7e7e7e;
}

.y.axis text {
  text-anchor: end !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  fill: #7e7e7e;
}

.domain {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  stroke: #2f5491;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  fill: none;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: #5e8dc9;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.selector li {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #fff;
}
.active {
  color: #c7003b
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="dropdown"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">

    <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
    <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span>
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes :) Great result.